# ViewPager & crash, after rotation and swipe, due to a nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I have a lengthy example, I created just for stack overflow. I can't seem to figure it out. I'm not a native Java programmer so that contributes to some confusion. But, this example requires 10 files, and is not just a code dump.

I've tried debugging this for numerous hours and as a last resort have created as concise of an example as I could of the issue, and have come here for help.

The following are the files, and at the bottom the stack trace. I'm really out of ideas of what to try. It's due to a nullpointerexception, that happens **after** I rotate the screen then try to slide in the ViewPager. I think should be an easy fix, but it hasn't been so for me.

Below are the java, and xml files, and stack trace. I think they are all necessary because they all are intertwined.

Here is a zip of the files too, if that's useful: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbv4irar727tp1x/CrashExample.zip?dl=0

**main.java**

```
package me.spencernusbaum.crashexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

/**
 * Created by Spencer on 4/26/2015.
 */
public class main extends FragmentActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        final List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

        Fragment f2 = new fragment_view();
        Fragment f1 = fragment_menu.newInstance(f2, pager);
        fragments.add(f1);
        fragments.add(f2);

        pager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager()) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int i) {
                return fragments.get(i);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return fragments.size();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**fragment_menu.java**

```
package me.spencernusbaum.crashexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Spencer on 4/26/2015.
 */
public class fragment_menu extends Fragment {

    Fragment fragment;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    public static final fragment_menu newInstance(Fragment f, ViewPager p) {
        fragment_menu result = new fragment_menu();
        result.fragment = f;
        result.viewPager = p;
        return result;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, null);

        result.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                ((fragment_view)fragment).setView(new fragment1());
                return false;
            }
        });
        result.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((fragment_view)fragment).setView(new fragment1());
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
            }
        });

        result.findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                ((fragment_view)fragment).setView(new fragment2());
                return false;
            }
        });
        result.findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((fragment_view)fragment).setView(new fragment2());
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
            }
        });

        return result;
    }
}
```

**fragment_view.java**

```
package me.spencernusbaum.crashexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Spencer on 4/26/2015.
 */
public class fragment_view extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, null);
    }

    public void setView(Fragment f) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, f).commit();
    }
}
```

**fragment1.java**

```
package me.spencernusbaum.crashexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Spencer on 4/26/2015.
 */
public class fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, null);
    }
}
```

**fragment2.java**

```
package me.spencernusbaum.crashexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Spencer on 4/26/2015.
 */
public class fragment2 extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, null);
    }
}
```

**fragment1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Fragment1"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Fragment 1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Fragment 2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

**viewpager.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**The Stack Trace:**

```
04-26 12:38:32.368    7635-7635/me.spencernusbaum.crashexample E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
        04-26 12:38:32.368    7635-7635/me.spencernusbaum.crashexample E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
        04-26 12:38:32.370    7635-7635/me.spencernusbaum.crashexample E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void me.spencernusbaum.crashexample.fragment_view.setView(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)' on a null object reference
        at me.spencernusbaum.crashexample.fragment_menu$1.onTouch(fragment_menu.java:32)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8382)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2739)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5646)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5791)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
        04-26 12:38:32.370    7635-7635/me.spencernusbaum.crashexample D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
        04-26 12:38:32.371    7635-7635/me.spencernusbaum.crashexample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: me.spencernusbaum.crashexample, PID: 7635
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void me.spencernusbaum.crashexample.fragment_view.setView(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)' on a null object reference
        at me.spencernusbaum.crashexample.fragment_menu$1.onTouch(fragment_menu.java:32)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8382)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2739)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5646)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5791)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the display is rotated, android (by default) destroys the current activity, including all fragments (the current state of attached fragments and the activity is saved via `onSaveInstanceState()`).

After the rotate, the activity and attached fragments are re-created (again: by default) and previously saved state is restored (passed as `Bundle` to `onCreate()`).

For fragments the android runtime **invokes their default, no-arguments constructor**.

The `newInstance()` method of your fragment is never invoked for the re-created fragment, hence your fields are not properly initialized and thus `null`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Is there a way to pass objects around then, though? Because my problem with the Bundle is it seemed like I could only store fundamental datatypes like int, string, etc. So I had done the work around method, so I could pass object, but I didn't realize the consequences of it.

Comment: Smells like the need for a controller object, created by the activity (it can also be the activity itself). Create a controller object inside your activity and fill it with the necessary information. Retrieve it in your fragments *when* they are attached to the activity. Also, there's also https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29. That probably won't work with the `ViewPager` though.

Comment: I tried the `setRetainInstance` and it works perfectly!